# Force redraw of Xamarin.Forms View with custom renderer

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a visual element `MyButton` with a custom renderer implemented for iOS.

Shared:

```
namespace RendererTest
{
    public class MyButton: Button
    {
        public Color BoundaryColor { get; set; }
    }

    public static class App
    {
        public static Page GetMainPage()
        {    
            var button = new MyButton { Text = "Click me!", BoundaryColor = Color.Red };
            button.Clicked += (sender, e) => (sender as MyButton).BoundaryColor = Color.Blue;
            return new ContentPage { Content = button };
        }
    }
}
```

iOS:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]

namespace RendererTest.iOS
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
    {
        public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
        {
            using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()) {
                context.SetFillColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToCGColor());
                context.SetStrokeColor((Element as MyButton).BoundaryColor.ToCGColor());
                context.SetLineWidth(10);
                context.AddPath(CGPath.FromRect(Bounds));
                context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When pressing the button, the red boundary should become blue. Apparently the renderer does not notice the changed property. How can I trigger a redraw?

[image]

(This example is for iOS. But my question applies to Android as well.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two modifications were required:

1. Call `OnPropertyChanged` within the setter of the `BoundaryColor` property:

   ```
   public class MyButton: Button
   {
       Color boundaryColor = Color.Red;

       public Color BoundaryColor {
           get {
               return boundaryColor;
           }
           set {
               boundaryColor = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();  // <-- here
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Subscribe to the event within the `OnElementChanged` method of `MyButtonRenderer`:

   ```
   public class MyButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
   {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           Element.PropertyChanged += (s_, e_) => SetNeedsDisplay();  // <-- here
       }

       public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
       {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:**
It seems to be important to subscribe within `OnElementChanged` and not the constructor. Otherwise a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` is raised.

Comment: What would be the equivalent for SetNeedsDisplay() to call on Android?

Comment: @kaolick: That would be `Invalidate()`.

Answer (score 10):

First, turn you `BoundaryColor` into a bindable property. That's not required, firing `INPC` event is enough, but then you can bind to it:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty BoundaryColorProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create ("BoundaryColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyButton), Color.Default);

public Color BoundaryColor {
    get { return (Color)GetValue (BoudaryColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue (BoundaryColorProperty, value); }
}
```

then, in your renderer:

```cs
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == MyButton.BoundaryColorProperty.PropertyName)
        SetNeedsDisplay ();
}
```

Comment: I tried to fire a ```public event Action BoundaryColorChanged``` when setting the ```BoundaryColor```. Within the ```MyButtonRenderer``` constructor I would subscribe to that event and call ```SetNeedsDisplay()```. If doing so, however, I get a ```System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException```.

Comment: It is working if I don't subscribe in the renderer's constructor, but within the ```Draw``` method. But this is probably not the best solution, since I'll keep adding (```+=```) listeners to the event.

Comment: you don't have to attach to the PropertyChanged event, `OnElementChanged` is already attached for you, you just have to override it.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix what is the equivalent of SetNeedsDisplay (); in Android? because I need to do it on Android too.